# Pinescript: Combining two indicators

Tags: pine-script

[Code and error message found here:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zp0N3.png)

So i'm trying to combine two indicators into one so I may use conditional statement to make trades. But i'm getting this error message. Could it be because the source is defined differently for the two different indicators? is there a way to make it work while being defined differently?

Comment: Please do not use screenshots. Copy and paste your code and error message to your original question and use `code` tags.

Comment: Also, line numbers in the error message do not match with your code. Did you change your code then take the screenshot with the old error messages?

Answer (score 0):

At the very beginning you have:

`source = hlc3`

First of all, `source` is a build-in variable in `pine-script` and you shouldn't name your variables after build-in variables. Second, `hlc3` is a `series` type.

Later you have:
`src = input(title="Source", type=source, defval=close)`

`type` parameter of the input function can only be one of: *bool*, *integer*, *float*, *string*, *symbol*, *resolution*, *session*, *source*. When you say `type=source`, it tries to use your variable, instead of using the build-in variable.

This is what the error message is telling you:

> Cannot call `input` with arguments (title=literal string, **type=series**,
>   defval=series); available overloads: input(const bool, const string,
>   const string, bool, const string) => bool; input(const integer, const
>   string, const string, integer, integer, bool, integer, [const
>   integer...], const string) => integer; input(const float, const
>   string, const string, float, float, bool, float, [const float...],
>   const string) => float; input(const string, const string, const
>   string, bool, [const string...], const string) => string;
>   input(series, const string, const string, const string) => series

You should rename your `source` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately modules/libraries are not yet supported in PineScript. So all you have to do is to rename 'source' variable in one of your scripts to say 'source2'